what is the rule for creating the raw encoding of a perfmon event with 2 event selectors
I have a sapphire rapids server. I'm interested is monitoring the perfmon event OCR.HWPF_L1D.ANY_RESPONSE. The associated information is
EventSel={2AH,2BH} UMask=01H MSR_OFFCORE_RSPx{1A6H,1A7H}=10400H
If this had 1 event selector the raw encoding would be the Umask followed by the EventSelector. But what is the raw encoding for an event that has 2 event selectors?
